# Where can I download previous builds of Windows 10 IOT Core

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot

It looks like there is a bug in the current version of Windows 10 IOT Core os for my RPi2. [It is causing it not to support the xbox 360 controller.](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SupportedInterfaces.htm)

So my question is where can I download previous builds of Windows 10 Iot Core?

I have been searching online and looked at the [official site](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/Downloads.htm) and my msdn subscription but cannot find a download link anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an insider perview image at [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com).

https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/Downloads

You will need a microsoft account and to join the Windows Embeded pre-release program [connect.microsoft.com](https://connect.microsoft.com) before the link will work.